# Why does a new bullet tunnel, when an old bullet does not?

Tags: java, jbox2d

I'm creating a game in Java using JBox2D which allows the player to shoot small high speed bullets.  When I create a bullet and apply a force in the direction of a wall, sometimes the bullet will tunnel though the wall.  This seems to depend on how close the bullet is to the wall when it is initially created.

For example, suppose I have a wall at x=5.  If I create a bullet, place it at x=0, and apply a 1000 Newton force, then the wall will successfully stop the bullet.  However, if I instead created the bullet at x=4, then the wall will NOT stop the bullet.

Here's an SSCCE for you all.  It was written as a TestbedTest to make testing even simpler.

```
import org.jbox2d.collision.shapes.CircleShape;
import org.jbox2d.collision.shapes.PolygonShape;
import org.jbox2d.common.Vec2;
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.Body;
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.BodyDef;
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.BodyType;
import org.jbox2d.testbed.framework.TestbedTest;

public class BulletTest extends TestbedTest
{
    @Override
    public String getTestName()
    {
        return "Bullet Test";
    }

    @Override
    public void initTest(boolean deserialized)
    {
        getWorld().setGravity(new Vec2());

        BodyDef wallBodyDef = new BodyDef();
        wallBodyDef.type = BodyType.STATIC;
        wallBodyDef.position.x = 5.0f;
        Body wallBody = getWorld().createBody(wallBodyDef);

        PolygonShape wallShape = new PolygonShape();
        wallShape.setAsBox(0.25f, 10.0f);
        wallBody.createFixture(wallShape, 1.0f);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(char keyChar, int keyCode)
    {
        switch (keyChar)
        {
        case '1':
            createBullet(0.0f);
            break;
        case '2':
            createBullet(4.0f);
            break;
        }
    }

    private void createBullet(float xPosition)
    {
        BodyDef bulletBodyDef = new BodyDef();
        bulletBodyDef.type = BodyType.DYNAMIC;
        bulletBodyDef.position.x = xPosition;
        bulletBodyDef.bullet = true; // shouldn't matter since the wall is static
        Body bulletBody = getWorld().createBody(bulletBodyDef);

        CircleShape bulletShape = new CircleShape();
        bulletShape.setRadius(0.125f);
        bulletBody.createFixture(bulletShape, 1.0f);

        bulletBody.applyForceToCenter(new Vec2(1000.0f, 0.0f));
    }
}
```

Comment: Collision detection is hard. I'm _guessing_ that when x=4 the bullet and the wall fail to see that they collided. When x=0, they do see they collide. Have you tried lowering the speed of the bullet? I'm guessing that would make it more likely to intersect the wall. Do you have any control over how a collision is determined?

Comment: Also, try making the wall thicker. I'm _guessing_ (as you can tell I don't have a lot of experience here) that wall/bullet collision is based on itterativively moving the bullet and then checking if the bullet and the wall intersect. If in one step the bullet moves further than the wall is thick then it can 'tunnel' through the wall. If the wall is thicker, it will be harder for the bullet to get through it.

Comment: @chessofnerd: Lowering the speed of the bullet does allow the collision detection to work properly, but then the bullet is moving at an undesirably slow speed for the game.  Increasing the size of the wall also helps, but then the walls are too big for the game as well.  JBox2D takes care of determining collisions, and there is limited control over changing its behavior without modifying the library itself.  In fact, for this type of collision it uses continuous collision detection, which makes it even more surprising that the collision isn't detected at all.

Comment: Humm, are there any properties on any of the framework that would change detection resolution? The continuous detection algorithm would suggest what I said is wrong. Have you tried x=4.01 or some other number close to but not equal to 4? I'd be curious to see if some of them make it through.

Comment: @chessofnerd: After rewriting my example to create 160 different bullets starting at x=2, and increasing x by 1/32 for each bullet, it seems like the problem starts at around x=3, and the only time it "works" after that, are for the bullets that start with positions inside the wall (glad at least those work).  Anyway, the results are perfectly deterministic, and so the same results occur every time.

Comment: Hum. I'd say that definitively shows it's not what I was thinking. I'm afraid I've got nothing else. You can definitely rethink the problem but I don't see anything inherently wrong with shooting a bullet when close to a wall. Good luck!